# Java print a huge string array as it is

Tags: java, string, delimiter

There is a string array, `row[]`, I want to put delimiters between them. I want to keep the order, so for example if

```
row[0] was "Gold",
row[1] was "Costly", 
row[2] was NULL,
row[3] was NULL, 
row[5] was "Bronze", 
row[6] was "Cheaper",
```

I want to retain the NULL values when I put a delimiter, say \t in the string array. So my new string should look like

```
'Gold \t Costly \t \t Bronze \t Cheaper'.
```

I can do something like

```
'System.out.println(row[0] + "\t" + row[1] +"\t" +row[2]+.......'
```

but the problem is the string array is more than 120 in length. Is there a better way to do this? (I can't use a for loop, since I'm out putting this in a mapper with other stuff). If it is String.format(), can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you make your question readable? Writing a clear & crisp question is the first step to get the right help.

Comment: The key from a performance standpoint is that if you're going to roll your own here (and I recommend that instead you use a pre-made library, such as the Guava one that @Ted Hopp mentioned), you want to use StringBuilder instead of raw string concatenation since you're concatenating more than two things.  (For only 2, + is just fine in most cases.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard API for this. There are several third-party packages that have a "join" method that does what you want (and then some). A particularly nice one is Guava's [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html). (Per Tim's comment, the [`StringUtils.join()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29) method in the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library also does everything you need.) Using a good third-party library can make a lot of these coding problems go away.

If you don't want (or are not allowed) to use a third-party library, you can write a method to concatenate the elements using the delimiter of your choice:

```
public static String join(String[] data, String delimiter) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        for (String item : data) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(item);
            sb.append(delimiter);
        }
        // chop off the last delimiter
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - delimiter.length());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can use `join()` wherever you were going to use your string concatenation expression. For example:

```
System.out.println(join(row, "\t"));
```

Comment: Apache Commons Lang has a [StringUtils.join()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29) method that does much the same thing.  But you should use something pre-built for a use-case like this; re-inventing basic wheels like this one is almost never a good idea, because it wastes your time and has a high risk that your implementation won't be as good as the one in the libraries you could be using.

Comment: @Tim - I agree that reinventing the wheel is to be avoided. Sometimes, though, developers are restricted from using third-party libraries, even good ones like Apache Commons or Guava.

Comment: @TedHopp thank you for pointing this out. I work in such an environment and its always very useful when people reinvent the wheel or at least discuss the implementation so that we may reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I know, also I work in some of those environments and I recognize that sometimes you roll your own because you can't get permission to bring in "risky" third-party libraries, which is why I think it's important for developers to use those libraries whenever they can, and only roll your own when you have to.

Comment: @Tim - Sometimes the barriers are simply technical. We have some apps for BlackBerry OS (pre-QNX), which requires the compiler to target Java 1.4. There is no way any substantive, third-party library is going to get packaged into one of those apps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `for` loop then:

```
String[] row = {"123",null,"ABC"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : row){
  if(s != null){
    sb.append(s);
  }

  sb.append("\t");
}
System.out.println("Your result string : "+sb.toString());
```

This prints:

```
Your result string : 123        ABC
```

Comment: OP wants to _retain_ NULL values. Also (per the example) there should not be a delimiter at the end of the string; just in between elements.